# trouble in sails lift on AWS server

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, sails.js

when I am running the project with `sails lift` then it shows -

```
Aborted due to warnings.
Running "sails-linker:devTpl" (sails-linker) task
padding length 4
Warning: Unable to write "views/layout.ejs" file (Error code: EACCES). 
------------------------------------------------------------------------

error: Looks like a Grunt error occurred--
error: Please fix it, then **restart Sails** to continue running tasks (e.g. watching for changes in assets)
error: Or if you're stuck, check out the troubleshooting tips below.

error: Troubleshooting tips:
error: 
error:  *-> Are "grunt" and related grunt task modules installed locally?  Run `npm install` if you're not sure.
error: 
error:  *-> You might have a malformed LESS, SASS, CoffeeScript file, etc.
error: 
error:  *-> Or maybe you don't have permissions to access the `.tmp` directory?
error:      e.g., `/var/myproj/.tmp` ?
error: 
error:      If you think this might be the case, try running:
error:      sudo chown -R 1000 /var/myproj/.tmp
```

I have tried all the given steps like provide access to .tmp and `npm install`
and when I am debugging the code by `sails debus` is shows :

```
Grunt :: Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::5858
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:860:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:883:20)
at Agent.Server._listen2 (net.js:1234:14)
at listen (net.js:1270:10)
at Agent.Server.listen (net.js:1366:5)
at Object.start (_debug_agent.js:21:9)
at startup (node.js:72:9)
at node.js:972:3
```

Strange part is its running on my local system and on normal(other) server very fine and correctly working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to chmod the views directory